# Expanding line to full width with only CSS

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

Maybe someone has any bright ideas how to replace my current solution to one of the problems via only CSS? I have a working JS solution, just curious if there is a CSS-only one.

[image]

A) Elements here have the same width, only the number of elements changes (can be more or less).

B) The line should expand to full width that is empty left here (the problem is here).

C) Text is dynamic (always other width).

Is it possible to set the B) element, so it would fill the width?

Comment: did you start from something? If yes, please provide your initial CSS, I would like to play with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible with `Flexbox`, you can just set `flex: 1` on lines and they will take rest of free space.

```css
.content,
.a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
}
.line {
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: With more than 92% of flexbox support in my country I should definitely start using it more and more. Thanks for the answer. I accept it :)